# Unable to avoid searching for invalid dependency in gradle build

Tags: gradle, plugins, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, launch4j

I try to include the Launch4J gradle plugin in our project.

```
plugins {
    id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' version '2.4.8'
}
```

However, the build fails with the following error.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find jai_core-1.1.3.jar (javax.media:jai_core:1.1.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/media/jai_core/1.1.3/jai_core-1.1.3.jar

Looking at the jcenter repository, the file is indeed missing. (But why does gradle not search the next repository in the list for it?)

So I try to exclude that dependency from jcenter like this:

```
jcenter() {
    content {
        excludeGroupByRegex "javax.media.*"
    }
}
```

...but still the same error.

I also tried to exclude the dependency from the plugin repository in settings.gradle like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        jcenter() {
            content {
                excludeGroupByRegex "javax.media.*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...but still the same error.

How can I include edu.sc.seis.launch4j but retrieve jai_core from a different repository?

I expect gradle to search for the dependency in the next repository in the list if it is not present or excluded in the current one.